# Python Popen process.poll() truncates the output

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a process running in the background and I'm capturing the stdout.

After reading every line of the stream `process.stdout.readline()` I do a time consuming operation `stdout_handler(current_time, stdout)` (a few miliseconds). This has to be done by line by line.

If I use `stdout_handler` my output is truncated around 250K... However, if I remove the `stdout_handler` I have the full output (~300K)...

The code is below.

```
    process = Popen(args, bufsize=1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
                    cwd=self.workdir, universal_newlines=True)

    rlist = [process.stdout, process.stderr]

    while process.poll() is None:
        ready, _, _ = select.select(rlist, [], [])

        current_time = now()
        if process.stdout in ready:
            stdout = process.stdout.readline()
            if stdout != '':
                stdout_handler(current_time, stdout)
```

Any idea how to sort this out?

Comment: When you say "truncated", how exactly does your program terminate? (For example, `stdout_handler` could be raising an exception...)

Comment: Terminates normally... It just doesn't capture the whole output.